# Recursive sorted file list (linux)

Tags: linux, file, find

I want to recurse through a directory, including in subdirectories and subdirectories of those and so on, printing out ONLY file names (no directories). I would also like to have the results on a new line each and sorted.

Please note that `ls -LR` or `ls -xLR` doesn't work as `ls` formats the result into a sort of table.

Guys, if you can edit it, do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go to the directory you want to search in, and run:

```
find . -type f -exec basename {} \; | sort
```

Sorted by name, just filenames (no paths), and just files (no directories).

---

Details:

- `find` works recursively, by default.
- `-type f` will print only files, not directories.
- `-exec basename` runs `basename` on the results (so paths are not printed).
- `sort` will sort the results (D'Oh!)

Comment: @Jack, yes, it is.  Did you try it?  I hope this helps :)

Comment: okay, it turns out that I have multiple files in different dirs named the same, so relative pathnames are good after all. removing '-exec basename {} \;' doesn't seem to do what I want.

Comment: @Jack, if you want to keep the relative paths, just do `find . -type f | sort`

Comment: okay, but what does the "./" character mean? isn't that a run command? (last question, I promise)

Comment: @Jack, The dot `.` is the current directory.  That is, your search starts in the current directory, recursively.

Comment: @jim +1, but the `.` is redundant and `-printf '%f\n'` would be faster/better than `-exec basename {} \;` to avoid subshells and extraneous commands.

Answer (score 0):

How about the 'find' and 'sort' utilities?

```
find <dir> -type f |sort
```

Comment: it says find: f: No such file or directory

Comment: @Jack, change `<dir>` for an actual directory, like `.` or `$HOME`

Answer (score 0):

That should work.  Did you typo? What version of linux do you have? See example below

```
testserver:~ # find /etc -type f | sort
/etc/.pwd.lock
/etc/DIR_COLORS
/etc/HOSTNAME
/etc/Muttrc 
....
....
/etc/zmd/zmd.conf
/etc/zshenv
/etc/zshrc
/etc/zypp/zypp.conf
testserver:~ #
```

(p.s. sorry tried to add as a comment, but my rep is not 50 so adding as an answer)